# Detect Install or Update inside the %install section

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

How can I differ from a fresh install of an update inside the %install section?
I can use the following code inside the %pre section, but it doesn't work inside the %install section:

```
if [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
    #install
else
    #update
fi
```

The main problem is that inside the %install section I want to copy some files (via cp command) only in the case of a fresh install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%install` sections runs during rpm creation. It doesn't run during rpm installation. It is for "installing" the packaged files so that the rpm creation process can find them.

tl;dr You can't do that.

You either always install them to somewhere temporary and only copy them to final locations when in fresh install mode or you use `%config(noreplace)` marking on files that need not to be modified on upgrade (when they've been modified locally already).